# Can I override the any ignore rule in .gitignore from .git/info/exclude

Tags: git, overriding, gitignore, ignore

I have created some rules for all repo user in .gitignore file.I need to ignore some rules without any change in the .gitignore. (these ignore rules should continue for other users) I know i can use "git add -f filename" command but  I don't want to point to a specific file/folder each time so I prefer to use "git add ."

I have the following rule in my .gitignore file

```
Source/Utils/*
```

and  I have tried to override it within my own .git/info/exclude. but it didn't work.

```
!Source/Utils/*
```

Do you have any information about override?

Comment: [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is it you want to accomplish that made you come up with this?

Comment: I should be able commit some directories while the directory ignore rule will continue in the project team.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to "un-ignore" a folder, the ignore rule should be:

```
myfolder/**
```

That is, you should ignore files only, not the folder itself because once a folder is ignored, no amount of ! rule would work.

Then you can un-ignore a folder content locally with:

```
!myfolder/
!myfolder/**
```

Note that ignore pattern are firt read in local `.gitignore`, then `info/exclude`: see [gitignore pattern man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_description).

That mean if you un-ignore first (in a local `.gitignore`), then the ignore rule in the `exclude` file will override that.
But if you ignore locally, then an un-ignore rule in `exclude` will work.

Comment: if i write them into the same config file i can un-ignore it as you mentioned it. but i use two config file. 
in .gitignore  : myfolder/**
in .git/info/exclude : !myfolder/**
It didn't work when I did it like this. but it works if I change places like this :

in .gitignore : !myfolder/**
in .git/info/exclude  : myfolder/**

as I mentioned before, I should not make a change in .gitignore. i think that the git/info/excludefile is being processed before gitignore.

Comment: @erdalt Yes, I have edited the answer to explain why, with a link to the documentation.